XSLT transformation - adding a node to an existing element
I'm trying to add a an extra node to an XML file using XSLT, but I have troubles with the namespaces.
Input XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AuditFile xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:doc="urn:schemas-OECD:schema-extensions:documentation">
  <Header>
    <AuditFileVersion>1.0</AuditFileVersion>
    <AuditFileCountry>DK</AuditFileCountry>
    <AuditFileDateCreated>2024-06-19</AuditFileDateCreated>
    <Company>
      <RegistrationNumber />
      <Name>usdk</Name>
      <Address>
        <StreetName />
        <Number />
        <City />
        <PostalCode />
        <Country>DK</Country>
        <AddressType>PostalAddress</AddressType>
      </Address>
      <Contact>
        <ContactPerson>
          <FirstName>NotUsed</FirstName>
          <LastName />
        </ContactPerson>
      </Contact>
      <TaxRegistration>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber />
        <TaxType>VAT</TaxType>
        <Country>DN</Country>
      </TaxRegistration>
    </Company>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>EUR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <SelectionCriteria>
      <SelectionStartDate>2024-06-19</SelectionStartDate>
      <SelectionEndDate>2024-06-19</SelectionEndDate>
    </SelectionCriteria>
    <TaxAccountingBasis>Fakturaregnskab</TaxAccountingBasis>
    <TaxEntity>Afdeling</TaxEntity>
  </Header>
</AuditFile>

Desired output (adding Telephone to Contact)
<AuditFile xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00">
  <Header>
    <AuditFileVersion>1.0</AuditFileVersion>
    <AuditFileCountry>DK</AuditFileCountry>
    <AuditFileDateCreated>2024-06-19</AuditFileDateCreated>
    <Company>
      <RegistrationNumber />
      <Name>usdk</Name>
      <Address>
        <StreetName />
        <Number />
        <City />
        <PostalCode />
        <Country>DK</Country>
        <AddressType>PostalAddress</AddressType>
      </Address>
      <Contact>
        <ContactPerson>
          <FirstName>NotUsed</FirstName>
          <LastName />
        </ContactPerson>
        <Telephone>123456789</Telephone>
      </Contact>
      <TaxRegistration>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber />
        <TaxType>VAT</TaxType>
        <Country>DN</Country>
      </TaxRegistration>
    </Company>
    <DefaultCurrencyCode>EUR</DefaultCurrencyCode>
    <SelectionCriteria>
      <SelectionStartDate>2024-06-19</SelectionStartDate>
      <SelectionEndDate>2024-06-19</SelectionEndDate>
    </SelectionCriteria>
    <TaxAccountingBasis>Fakturaregnskab</TaxAccountingBasis>
    <TaxEntity>Afdeling</TaxEntity>
  </Header>
</AuditFile>

After some struggling I came up with the following XSLT:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:faia="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK">
  <xsl:variable name="urnStandardAuditFile">urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00</xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$urnStandardAuditFile}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="faia:Contact">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <Telephone></Telephone>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

But that keeps giving me nodes with namespaces, which I don't want.
<Contact xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK">
    <ContactPerson xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00">
        <FirstName>NotUsed</FirstName>
        <LastName/>
    </ContactPerson>
    <Telephone xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00">123456789</Telephone>
    <Telephone xmlns=""/>
</Contact>

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I think that all you need to do is just:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dk="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK"
xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dk:Contact">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Telephone>123456789</Telephone>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Take notice of the double declaration of the same namespace in the stylesheet:
xmlns:dk="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK"
xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK"

The first one allows you to match the Contact element using the assigned prefix. The other declares a default namespace for the added Telephone element, so that it matches its parent's namespace.

Added:
If you also want to change the XML document's default namespace (IOW, to rename each and every element in the given input) you will need to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dk="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK"
xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00"
exclude-result-prefixes="dk">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dk:Contact">
    <Contact>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Telephone>123456789</Telephone>
    </Contact>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

If it's important to have the additional namespace declarations at the root element (which aren't used anywhere in the document) then also add this template:
<xsl:template match="/dk:AuditFile">
    <AuditFile xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:doc="urn:schemas-OECD:schema-extensions:documentation">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </AuditFile>
</xsl:template>


That did indeed add the telephone, but the namespaces in the output file are not correct. The root is now <AuditFile xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-Financial:DK" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:doc="urn:schemas-OECD:schema-extensions:documentation">, but it should be <AuditFile xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Taxation/2.00"> instead.

@SabrinaL., your input has the two namespaces (e.g. xs and doc) and the code just copies nodes. Stripping namespaces from the input document can be achieved although it is a bit easier in XSLT 2 or later with copy-namespaces="no" and the ability to create result namespaces explicitly.

@MartinHonnen Thanks for the reply. I think 2.0 could work as well, but can you provide me the XSLT then? Just adding copy-namespaces="no" didn't work.

@SabrinaL. This requirement was not in your original question, and it changes the task significantly. I have added to my answer, but you should not make such sweeping change to your question after it has been answered. Even your title is now wrong: you are no longer adding to an existing element, but to a new one.

'copy-namespaces="no"on e.g.xsl:copy` needs an XSLT 2 or 3 processor. And it is only helpful to get rid of superfluous namespace nodes/declarations, it seems you want a completely different namespace for the result elements, but it looks as if the edit by @y.arazim has you covered.

@y.arazim Indeed, there was a copy/paste error in my initial question. But thanks for the edit, it solved my problem!
